# Is there a python library/module for creating a multi ssh connection?

Tags: python, ruby, ssh

I've been searching for a library that can access multiple ssh connections at once, Ruby has a Net::SSH::Multi module that allows multiple ssh connections at once. However I rather prefer coding this in Python, are there any similar SSH module for python?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185855/parallel-ssh-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) is Python's SSH library.

I've never tried concurrent connections with Paramiko, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185855/parallel-ssh-in-python/1188586#1188586) says it's possible, and [this little script](http://www.packetstormsecurity.org/Crackers/mtsshbrute.py.txt) seems to make multiple connections in different threads.

The Paramiko mailing list also [confirms it's possible to make multiple connections by forking](http://www.lag.net/pipermail/paramiko/2008-January/000599.html) -- there was a security issue regarding that, and it was patched in early 2008.